# Tensor conversion requested dtype int64 for Tensor with dtype float32 when creating CNN model

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, data-science

I tried to create a CNN but I got an error. Could you figure out what I did wrong?

```py
C1, C2 = tf.constant(70, dtype='float32'), tf.constant(1000, dtype="float32")

def score(y_true, y_pred):
    tf.dtypes.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
    tf.dtypes.cast(y_pred, tf.float32)
    sigma = y_pred[:, 2] - y_pred[:, 0]
    fvc_pred = y_pred[:, 1]

    # sigma_clip = sigma + C1
    sigma_clip = tf.maximum(sigma, C1)
    delta = tf.abs(y_true[:, 0] - fvc_pred)
    delta = tf.minimum(delta, C2)
    sq2 = tf.sqrt(tf.dtypes.cast(2, dtype=tf.float32))
    metric = (delta / sigma_clip) * sq2 + tf.math.log(sigma_clip * sq2)

    return K.mean(metric)
```

```py
def mloss(_lambda):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return _lambda * qloss(y_true, y_pred) + (1 - _lambda) * score(y_true, y_pred)

    return loss
```

```py
def make_model():
    z = L.Input((9,), name="Patient")
    x = L.Dense(100, activation="relu", name="d1")(z)
    x = L.Dense(100, activation="relu", name="d2")(x)
    
    p1 = L.Dense(3, activation="linear", name="p1")(x)
    p2 = L.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="p2")(x)
    preds = L.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + tf.cumsum(x[1], axis=1), name="preds")([p1, p2])

    model = M.Model(z, preds, name="CNN")

    model.compile(loss=mloss(0.8), optimizer="adam", metrics=[score])
    return model
```

```py
net = make_model()

net.fit(z[tr_idx], y[tr_idx], batch_size=200, epochs=1000,
        validation_data=(z[val_idx], y[val_idx]), verbose=0)
```

> Error here: ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int64 for
> Tensor with dtype float32: <tf.Tensor 'CNN/preds/add:0' shape=(None,
> 3) dtype=float32>

type cast but didn't solve the problem